# how to detect and get url on string javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

how to detect and get url on string javascript?

example :

```
var string = "hei dude, check this link http:://google.com and http:://youtube.com"
```

how to get result like this from my string :

```
var result = ["http:://google.com", "http:://youtube.com"]
```

how do that?

Comment: For URLs in natural language texts, there are many exceptions to consider. Why not use a library like this? https://github.com/Andrew-Kang-G/url-knife

Comment: Dupe isn't correct because OP is trying to find matches that look like URLs here but not wellformed URL due to use of double `::` after `http`.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You input has double `::` after `http`. Not sure if it intentional. If it is then use:

```
var matches = string.match(/\bhttps?::\/\/\S+/gi);
```

If only one `:` is needed then use:

```
var matches = string.match(/\bhttps?:\/\/\S+/gi);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xD8aL0/1)

Comment: 100% right.. i am also do this..

Comment: var matches = string.match(/\bhttp?::\/\/\S+/gi); console.log(matches)

Comment: great @anubhava thank you

Comment: It seems that it doesn't detect: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eogv_ItM9s8"

Comment: That is not that simple. You have to consider many exceptional cases.

Answer (score 6):

```js
const string = "hei dude, check this link http:://google.com and http:://youtube.com"
const matches = string.match(/\bhttp?::\/\/\S+/gi);
console.log(matches);
```