# Regex Pattern to extract url links from two string

Tags: regex

I have two string in which I have to sorten urls. I want a regex pattern to extract them

```
https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Febay.to%2F2EyH7Nq&h=ATNHM5kACc4rh_z68Ytw__cNCzJ63_iPezd_whc0PjcsN4qj1PfdJgFXyrOKM3-biqPm7eAXTOc5LD6r-7JXhRsqsqEHUs0jaJkjvm_QWf6sqbHQmS63q6P0_NcQoUa86Az5EttNT9xJb_evKBaiFxW7e7v2afJQn2zNxz5lQ8xgxhMcEFuJ3hUiSYUMEemKFB2LSIgAZFibRv4GeRrTk8hxFaArkBuAhQaXQFd4jX-aQuUYhjD0ErV5FY-D4gFMpb0lFCU7SyBlRpkUuOcHVjwjxN-_g6reMYwo8loAJnJD
/redirect?q=http%3A%2F%2Fgoo.gl%2FIW7ct&redir_token=PV5sR8F7GuXT9PgPO_nkBFLABQx8MTUxNjA3OTY5MEAxNTE1OTkzMjkw&v=7wmIyD1fM4M&event=video_description
```

Output will be from 1st and 2nd link:-

```
http%3A%2F%2Febay.to%2F2EyH7Nq
http%3A%2F%2Fgoo.gl%2FIW7ct
```

Please help me out.
I have already used:-
`(http|https).*?&`

but its not working on first url.

Comment: possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33211233/how-to-detect-and-get-url-on-string-javascript

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
=(https?[^&]*)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/K2zCNv/5)

If lookbehind is possible in your flavour of regex then you may try this as well which will ensure to not capture the equal sign:

```
(?<=)(https?[^&]*)
```

[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/K2zCNv/4/)

Comment: Might be worth adding a capture group to make it easy to ditch the `=`... Or look-behind ;)

Comment: You are right MatBailie, in the mean time I was trying to just match the desired thing thus come the lookbehind regex. Btw added capture group to the first solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex !

I am also attach the output of the regex through regex101.

```
http%3A%2F%2F(.*)%2F(.*[^&])(?=&)
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern to only capture `goo.gl` and `ebay.to` links:

```
(http%3A%2F%2F(ebay\.to|goo\.gl)%2F[^&]*)&
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/O0NJoF/3)