# How to get url from string in freemarker

Tags: javascript, freemarker

Is there a way to get the URL from below text using freemarker `replace` or `matches` available in freemarker built ins.

```
<#assign text = "There are some text with url like https://www.google.com" />
```

I Want something like below to get the url from this text.

```
${text?matches('some freemarker regex')}  // expected: https://www.google.com
```

I searched on internet and found the same in javascript but don't know how to convert it in freemarker.
[how to detect and get url on string javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33211233/how-to-detect-and-get-url-on-string-javascript)

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression to match URLs in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163360/regular-expression-to-match-urls-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need regex for this. Try something like:

```
<#assign text = "There are some text with url like https://www.google.com" >
<#list text?split(" ") as x>
<#if x?starts_with("http")>${x}</#if>
</#list>
```

Output:

```
https://www.google.com
```